# Filling asp controls using Client Side C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

It's been a long time since I've used classic asp.net and asp: controls.

I have this textbox;

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" CssClass="fieldLge" Text='<%= this.Title %>'/>
```

In my cs I have;

```
 public string Title { get; set; }
```

The property is being set from a presenter.

However when I see my field on screen I see "<%= this.Title %>" as it's text and not the value of the property.

I know this is a mind numbingly silly question to ask but I can't figure it out.  Love MVC!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MVP with Webforms you would normally set properties on controls directly from the property in the view interface.

change:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public string Title 
{ 
    get { return txtTitle.Text } 
    set { txtTitle.Text = value }
}
```

Comment: +1.  Boy it has been a long time.  I remeber doing this now.  Thanks a bunch @rabs.  Will mark as correct in 6 minutes